# Is there a way to output the process ID in a surefire build with forkCount > 1?

Tags: maven, jenkins, fork, maven-surefire-plugin

we have jenkins build which run about 500 different testclasses. When multiple tests fail it sometimes would be helpful to know, if they ran on the same process. Does anybody know a way to let surefire output the process Id. I did not find anything in the plugin-documentation

Answer (score 2):

There is not official API to get the pid prior to Java 9.

If you are using a different version you may ant to look at there hacks:

http://www.golesny.de/p/code/javagetpid

Comment: Thank you, That might be the cause, why surefire does not output the process id, but does not help very much, since I don't want to change surefire by myself.

Comment: Since the unit tests are executed within the surefire process you can just add that to you unit tests.

Comment: Thanks once more, but I thought about a bit less intruding solution. As I mentioned there are about 500 Unittestclasses. Additionally I would have prefered the pid, or something which signifies which testclasses ran on the same vm, to be output by surefire itself, so that it can be seen in the jenkins console protocol.